# How to unify these types?

Tags: types, purescript

I have the following code from purescript-express (but the question is more general).

```
setHandler :: forall e. Handler e
setHandler = do
    idParam   <- getRouteParam "id"
    send "Yeah! "

appSetup :: forall e. App e
appSetup = do
    get "/set/:id" setHandler
```

`setHandler` needs to have the given signature as `get` is defined as

```
> :t get
forall e r.
(RoutePattern r) => r
                    -> HandlerM ( express :: EXPRESS | e ) Unit
                    -> AppM ( express :: EXPRESS | e ) Unit
```

Now however I want to use the following function within `setHandler`

```
getPointsSet :: forall f. String -> Aff ( fs :: FS | f ) Foobar
```

which will give me the following compiler error

```
[1/1 TypesDoNotUnify] src/Main.purs:31:5

          v
  31      send "Yeah! "
          ^

  Could not match type

    HandlerM

  with type

    Aff

  while trying to match type HandlerM
                               ( express :: EXPRESS
                               | _2
                               )
    with type Aff
                ( fs :: FS
                | _0
                )
  while checking that expression send "Yeah! "
    has type Aff
               ( fs :: FS
               | _0
               )
               _1
  in value declaration setHandler
```

I understand that using `getPointsSet` effectively requires setHandler to become a `Aff` as well but than I cannot wire it up with the `get` then.

**Edit**

If I try to add a `liftAff` as suggested in the answer below

```
setHandler :: forall e. Handler e
setHandler = do
    idParam   <- getRouteParam "id"
    liftAff $ getPointsSet "../some-data.csv"
    send "Yeah! "
```

I get the following error

```
[1/1 NoInstanceFound] src/Main.purs:28:1
   28  setHandler :: forall e. Handler e
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   No type class instance was found for
   Control.Monad.Aff.Class.MonadAff ( fs :: FS | _0 )
                                 (HandlerM ( express :: EXPRESS | e0 ))

The instance head contains unknown type variables. Consider adding a type annotation.
in value declaration setHandler
```

What do I need to do to resolve that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that `HandlerM` has instance of `MonadAff`, so you can use `liftAff`. Like here:

```
setHandler :: forall e. Handler e
setHandler = do
  idParam   <- getRouteParam "id"
  liftAff $ getPointsSet "foo"
  send "Yeah! "
```

Ah, sorry, rows don't unify without additional annotation of `appSetup` and `setHandler`

**updated version**

```
appSetup :: forall e. App (fs :: FS|e)
appSetup =
  get "/set/:id" setHandler

setHandler :: forall e. Handler (fs :: FS|e)
setHandler = do
  idParam   <- getRouteParam "id"
  liftAff $ getPointsSet "../some-data.csv"
  send "Yeah! "
```

You need to alter `main` type also

```
main :: forall e. Eff (express :: EXPRESS, fs :: FS|e) Unit
```

Comment: yup - that was it. Sort of ;-) actually what also works is simply not having a signature for setHandler

Answer (score 1):

To expand upon Максим's answer,

Your `setHandler` has the type `forall e. Handler e` which is equivalent to `HandlerM (express :: EXPRESS | e) Unit`
which in turn is equivalent to `HandlerM (Request -> Response -> Eff (express :: EXPRESS | e) Unit -> Aff (express :: EXPRESS | e) Unit)`. if we take out the function from the constructor and feed it with arguments (as some function probably does behind the scenes) we are left with `Aff (express :: EXPRESS | e) Unit)`

Your `getPointsSet` has the type `forall f. String -> Aff ( fs :: FS | f ) Foobar`

So basically our problem can be reduced to this: the type `(express :: EXPRESS | e)` does not unify with `( fs :: FS | f )`, this means that in order to call `getPointsSet` from `setHandler`, `setHandler` has to supply a `String` (you supplied `"foo"`) and the effect `FS` which it currently does not supply. in order to supply it, the type signature of `setHandler` has to change, so instead of `Aff (express :: EXPRESS | e) Unit)` we want to have `Aff (express :: EXPRESS, fs :: FS | r)`. now the exact same analysis needs to be done for `main` and `setHandler` as well, `setHandler` needs the effect `FS` which main does not supply. the same change will need to be made.

I hope this make sense.